# Передать результат запроса в переменную

Tags: javascript

Как можно передать результат fetch запрса в переменную, что бы не делать запрос каждый раз?

```
async function getBase() {
    let responseItems = await fetch(urlAllBase);
    items = await responseItems.text();

    return parseArrays(JSON.parse(items));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как - то попробуйте.

```
let base;
async function getBase() {
    if(!base){
      let responseItems = await fetch(urlAllBase);
      base = parseArrays(JSON.parse(await responseItems.text());
    }
    return base;
}
```